# Which states offer PE licensure for Software Engineering?

Tags: licensure, software

Which U.S. states offer Professional Engineer (PE) licensure for software engineering?

In my research, few of the state licensing boards listed on the [NCEES site](http://ncees.org/licensing-boards/) include the Software Engineering discipline.  Most focus on engineering disciplines such as Civil, Chemical, etc.

When I checked with NCEES, they recommended contacting each state **individually**!  Yuck.

Comment: Related: [Can Software Engineers become certified Professional Engineers (PE)?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39541/can-software-engineers-become-certified-professional-engineers-pe)

Comment: http://ncees.org/licensing-boards/ from http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/148768/119759

Comment: I can't help but post this link: [Programmers: Stop Calling Yourselves Engineers](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2015/11/programmers-should-not-call-themselves-engineers/414271/)

Comment: @NickAlexeev - I see you and raise you by one: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2011/10/28/dont-call-yourself-a-programmer/

Comment: [slide 21](http://www.ieeeusa.org/careers/webinars/2014/slides/04-09-14-IEEE-PE-Webinar.pdf)

Comment: And when you contacted each state individually, what did you learn? Which states refused to divulge the information, or made obtaining it so onerous, that you had no recourse but to come here and ask someone else to do what you decided wasn't worth your time to do? -1.

Comment: @Air: You mean, other than the fact that there are *50* such states?

Comment: @Robert Yes, other than that. This is not much better IMO than students asking us to complete homework assignments they feel are too tedious; the answer is there, go and get it. Sometimes due diligence is tedious, should we farm that out as well?

Comment: @Air: Your Help Center says this question is off-topic; there's a close link right below the question. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't agree that it's off-topic, despite being skeptical about its value. Feel free to join the ongoing discussion in [chat].